# Dificulty installing Linux Mint on Thinkpad t430

Tags: boot, installation, linux-mint, thinkpad

I'm trying to install Linux Mint MATE edition on an empty SSD on my laptop through a bootable USB stick. When I turn on the laptop it does show the menu giving me the option to start Linux mint, but when I press Enter it doesn't do anything and eventually shows me these error messages:

https://pomf2.lain.la/f/lm07e6xd.jpg

I have already looked for the correct BIOS settings but for some reason it's still not working. Could it be a problem with the USB stick?

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: Yes, it's likely a problem with the installation/live media. Check the ISO before anything else and do it again / use another USB, etc.

Comment: Thank you. It was in fact the USB stick for some reason. Used another one and it worked.